# Enviar y recibir datos a nodejs desde formualario javascript con fetch

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo un problema para enviar datos por POST desde el formulario a nodejs. Aun no logro encontrar una forma de enviar los datos de manera correcta, no me sale error solo un String vacío.

## Código en NodeJS

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static('./public'))

app.post('/formulario', async(req, res) =>{
  console.log("entre")
  const nombre = req.body; // no se si era body o params así que hice los dos
  const nombre2 = req.params;
  
  await console.log(nombre)
  res.json({nombre, nombre2})
})
 
app.listen(8080, ()=>{
    console.log("server on port 8080")
})
```

## Código en JavaScript

No se si esa se la manera correcta de enviar los datos, he escuchado que con FormData pero por el momento solo quiero enviar algo

```
enviar.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value //Obtengo el valor del input nombre
    nombre = JSON.stringify(nombre);
    e.preventDefault()
    
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/formulario',  // fetch para enviar el dato
    {
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: nombre //Aquí se envía
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data)) // aquí lo muestro en la consola
})
```

## Formulario en HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hola mundo</h1>
    <form action="/formulario" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="nombre">nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="enviar">
    </form>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hay varios problemas en tu código, pero a simple vista podría decir que se debe a que no tienes un middleware como [body parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) para parsear el body de la petición que recibas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comenta Benjamín, Node por si solo no tiene la capacidad de identificar la data enviada, entoces habrá que pasarla por `bodyParser`

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Luego seteamos el `body-parser` como middleware en tu aplicación principal.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }) );
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
```

De esta forma ya deberías tener algo en tu `req.body`

Comment: Si gracias si me funciono ahora solo me queda obtenerla y mostrarla en el frontEnd. Sin recargar pagina, he intentado el e.preventDefault() y con la misma petición de JavaScript pero no me funciona, es como si no enviara nada.

Comment: si estas usando las ultimas versiones de node en vez de bodyparser, que esta depreciado deberias usar app.use(express.json()). Si has prevenido el submit para enviar por fetch url enconded no es necesario. Y tambien podrias usar un formData para enviar el formulario